# Error Undefined function in Erlang

Tags: erlang, undefined-function

This on compiling gives {ok,assignment5}.

```
 three_a(F) -> fun(Y) -> lists:foldl(F,0,Y).
```

After writing this

```
F1=assignment5:three_a(fun(X,Sum) -> X+Sum end).
```

Gives

```
** exception error: undefined function assignment5:three_a/1
```

Please help out!

Comment: Assuming your first line shown is in a module named `assignment5`, does the module also specify `-export([three_a/1]).`?

Comment: Yes , I was in the wrong directory :( . Thanks for the help , but on compiling now the error coming is     
1)     syntax error before: '.'
2)    function three_a/1 undefined

Comment: Yes, because you need `end` before the `.` to close off the `fun`.

Comment: Yes correct, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

All `funs` ([anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)) start with `fun(.)` and end with `end`.[1](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#fun-expressions)

With the syntax fix it will work like this:

```
1> three_a(F) -> fun(Y) -> lists:foldl(F,0,Y).
* 1:12: syntax error before: '->'
1> three_a(F) -> fun(Y) -> lists:foldl(F,0,Y) end.
ok
2> F1= three_a(fun(X,Sum) -> X+Sum end).
#Fun<erl_eval.42.125776118>
3>
```